# Create javascript file from php array_push and loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have array generated in php like this:

```
array_push($json, (object)[
  'location_lat' => $spot_lat,
  'location_lng' => $spot_lng,
  'cat' => $spot_category,
  'additional' => $spot_additional
]);
```

This code is in mine 'while' loop. And the end of my function I'm doing this:

```
  $fp = fopen('my-path/spots.js', 'w');
  $addressPoints = json_encode($json);
  fwrite($fp, $addressPoints);
  fclose($fp);
```

All working well, I'm getting fine spots.js file looking like this:

```
[{"location_lat":"49.6149366","location_lng":"22.2754669","cat":"na-dziko","additional":["is_verified","paid","bike","fishing","pitch","shop","river","lake","forest","buildings","playground","sanitary","wifi","barbecue","kitchen","year","electricity"]},{"location_lat":"49.4257138","location_lng":"20.4740524","cat":"kempingi-i-pola-namiotowe","additional":["paid","bike","trails","river","forest","mountains","sanitary","barbecue","kitchen","electricity"]},{"location_lat":"44.52625","location_lng":"1.71944","cat":"kempingi-i-pola-namiotowe","additional":["paid","bike","pool","fishing","water_sport","trails","climber","6","Array","shop","river","forest","mountains","4","Array","sanitary","wifi","kitchen","restaurant","electricity","5","Array"]}]
```

But the problem is i dont know how to set this array as variable? I need to generate my .js file like this:

```
var myCustomVariable = [{"location_lat":"49.6149366","location_lng":"22.2754669","cat":"na-dziko","additional":["is_verified","paid","bike","fishing","pitch","shop","river","lake","forest","buildings","playground","sanitary","wifi","barbecue","kitchen","year","electricity"]},{"location_lat":"49.4257138","location_lng":"20.4740524","cat":"kempingi-i-pola-namiotowe","additional":["paid","bike","trails","river","forest","mountains","sanitary","barbecue","kitchen","electricity"]},{"location_lat":"44.52625","location_lng":"1.71944","cat":"kempingi-i-pola-namiotowe","additional":["paid","bike","pool","fishing","water_sport","trails","climber","6","Array","shop","river","forest","mountains","4","Array","sanitary","wifi","kitchen","restaurant","electricity","5","Array"]}]
```

The solution is probably very simple, but I can't do it.

Comment: Concatenate the strings? Just add `var myCustomVariable = ` before the JSON encoded array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$addressPoints** is a string. So you can simply add the desired var declaration to it:

```
$addressPoints = 'var myCustomVariable = ' . json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Thanks, i know that's very simple :)